# WPF компонент не рисуется полностью

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Имеется окно с вставленным самодельным компонентом, которой чем-то загораживается.
Как будто какая-то невидимая зона сбоку (показал желтой линией), которая перекрывает его (аналогично и снизу).
Если изменять размер окна, она двигается.

[image: баг]

Код окна следующий

```xml
<Window>
    <Grid>

        <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="↻" Margin="10,10,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <local:Clock x:Name="clock" Width="250" Height="250" Margin="10,10,72,33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <Label x:Name="labelHours" Content="0 h." HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="21.333" />
        <Label x:Name="labelPass" Content="0 h." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="21.333" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Сам компонент имеет следующую структуру

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
        <!-- далее несколько внутренних canvas-ов -->
        <Canvas>
            <Path/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Кто подскажет в чем проблема, чем его загораживает?

Comment: А чего у вас размеры и у канваса заданы и у часов в окне? уберите в любом одном месте обозначение размеров.

Comment: Зачем вам Margin со значениями типа 72? Вы не в WinForms, используйте layout manager. Пишите `Margin="10"`.

Comment: @Monk Убрал задание высоты компоненту и попустило

Comment: @VladD было много экспериментов, а так вы правы

Comment: @ОлексійЛогвиненко: Окей. В любом случае, лучше не накладывать слишком много условий, а то они могут войти в противоречие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По советам из комментариев убрал margin и задание размеров компоненту, что решило проблему.